# Inset > Extrude > Bevel > Subdiv = Weird?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

On Default Cube, select face, Inset it, Extrude it 'inside' the cube, add Bevel and Subdivision.
This is the result.

I recently switched to the latest Blender version, and I could be wrong, but I don't remember the same behaviour in older version.

This is Default Cube, no extra vertices, no wrong face orientation.. And on Cylinder the process is working as expected.
If I switch Subdivision to Simple, it looks as expected, but somewhat rough.

Why is that? What am I not understanding?
[image]

Comment: It depends on your bevels I reckon

Comment: Well, if I change 'limit method' from default angle 30 to none, then it's ok.
But I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 4):

Catmull-Clark Subdivision Surface smoothens the mesh by interpolating values of nearby vertices. If there's not enough holding loops this smoothing can actually create sharp geometry like so:

[image]

The key is to have quads wherever normals change, as well as to have the quad loops flow with a consistent way to the smoothed mesh:

[image]